# SQL create table statement as it is showing right parenthesis error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table customer
(
    cusno int Primary key auto increment,
    custname varchar(32),
    address varchar(200),
    internal varchar(55),
    contact varchar(11),
    phone  varchar(12), 
    city varchar (24),
    state varchar(23), 
    zip varchar(10) 
);
```

Please ignore other things.

Comment: Where in the [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find `auto increment`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an "auto increment" in Oracle (12.1 and later) use an [identity column](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAECCFH).

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    cusno    number generated BY DEFAULT AS identity,
    custname VARCHAR(32),
    address  VARCHAR(200),
    internal VARCHAR(55),
    contact  VARCHAR(11),
    phone    VARCHAR(12),
    city     VARCHAR (24),
    state    VARCHAR(23),
    zip      VARCHAR(10)
);
```

While `int` or `integer` are accepted as a data type, they are only an alias for the native data type `number`

Comment: `int[eger]` is **not** an alias for `number`. `int` is an alias for `number(38,0)`. That is, it WILL only store integer values (even if the input is not an integer) - and, as with many similar things Oracle does, this will happen without warning. (There is no data type check for "integer" against "3.3", for example; Oracle will silently round it to 3 and store 3 in the database.)